# How to pass "-v" argument for Python in PyCharm IDE

Tags: python, pycharm

I want to run a Python program in verbose mode in PyCharm IDE. I specified `"-v"` in Interpreter option under Run/Debug Configurations window. But it shows the following error:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7
/home/user1/Downloads/pycharm-community-2016.1.4/helpers/pydev/pydev_run_in_console.py
35261 34268 -v
/home/user1/my_codings/gitStuffs/Cura_Debian_Release/usr/share/cura/cura.py
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/home/user1/Downloads/pycharm-community-2016.1.4/helpers/pydev/pydev_run_in_console.py",
line 71, in <module>
    globals = run_file(file, None, None)   File "/home/user1/Downloads/pycharm-community-2016.1.4/helpers/pydev/pydev_run_in_console.py",
line 31, in run_file
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '-v' Running -v
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work if you run it like this:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 -v /home/user1/my_codings/gitStuffs/Cura_Debian_Release/usr/share/cura/cura.py
```

If you need debugger (or to add other files) then `-v` should go first:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 -v /home/user1/Downloads/pycharm-community-2016.1.4/helpers/pydev/pydev_run_in_console.py 35261 34268 /home/user1/my_codings/gitStuffs/Cura_Debian_Release/usr/share/cura/cura.py
```

In PyCharm you should add `-v /home/user1/Downloads/pycharm-community-2016.1.4/helpers/pydev/pydev_run_in_console.py 35261 34268` inside `Interpreter options`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But i want to do it from pyCharm itself. I need to know the location where I can put the -v

Comment: @PraveenMax Please edit your question and add information from Run/Debug Configuration. Especially what you have in `Script parameters` and `Interpreter options`.